# Result of SQL to Userfunc in TypoScript

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I am very new to Typo3/TypoScript and I wondered if and how it is possible to give the result of a sql-statement in TypoScript to a php function.

I've managed the userFunc so far, but i'm getting confused with the rest.
Here is my try:

```
temp.pidList = CONTENT
temp.pidList {
  table = tx_eepcollect_sessions
  #table = tt_content
  select {
    pidInList < plugin.tx_eepcollect_pi1.pid_list
   where {
      stdWrap.cObject = TEXT
      stdWrap.cObject {
        data = global : _COOKIE | tx_eepcollect_pi1
        wrap = ses_id='|'
      }
    }
  }
  renderObj = COA
  renderObj {
    10 = TEXT
    10.field = ses_data
    #30 = TEXT
    #30.data = debug:data
  }
}


includeLibs.user_idList = fileadmin/services/user_IdList.php
temp.ListOfIds = USER
temp.ListOfIds.userFunc = user_IdList->get_IdList
#temp.pidList = TEXT
#temp.pidList = {"1275":{"id":"1275","tx_eepcollect_pi1":{"prozess":"add","pid":"1275","ctrl":"1360858765"},"cHash":"e90b62584f3f0e4f71bf1100faf39d83"}}
temp.ListOfIds.userFunc.jsonList < temp.pidList


temp.mainContent = COA_INT
temp.mainContent.10 = TEXT
temp.mainContent.10.stdWrap.cObject < temp.ListOfIds
```

The output is an array of a lot of stuff, but not the result of the database-query.

Comment: What is exactly needed? the output of temp.pidList or temp.ListOfIds ?
If you are asking about the userfunc, then please copy-paste the php code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypoScript is not a programming language, so it is not executed in any meaning. You should think about TS as set of instructions for the Core.
So, following line:

```
temp.ListOfIds.userFunc.jsonList < temp.pidList
```

will not put result of **temp.pidList** into **temp.ListOfIds.userFunc.jsonList**, as you would expect from a programming language - it will simply copy set of instructions, so at the end you'll have following structure:

```
temp.ListOfIds = USER
temp.ListOfIds.userFunc = user_IdList->get_IdList
temp.ListOfIds.userFunc.jsonList = CONTENT
temp.ListOfIds.userFunc.jsonList.table = tx_eepcollect_sessions
[...]
```

And since **jsonList** is your custom property you need to bring [stdWrap](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Functions/Stdwrap/Index.html) to it by following method:

**TypoScript**

```
temp.ListOfIds.userFunc.jsonList.cObject < temp.pidList
```

**PHP**

```
$jsonList = $this->cObj->stdWrap($conf['jsonList'], $conf['jsonList.']);
```

I assume, that you call it from a method **get_IdList** of class **user_IdList** with two params: *$content* and *$conf*.

As an additional measerue, you can make it as extension with a [kickstarter](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/kickstarter) or [extension builder](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/extension_builder), so it'll be easier for you to work with configuration.

Another thing is, that your code have potential SQL injection vulnerability here:

```
   where {
      stdWrap.cObject = TEXT
      stdWrap.cObject {
        data = global : _COOKIE | tx_eepcollect_pi1
        wrap = ses_id='|'
      }
    }
```

So, you may consider reading about [markers](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Functions/Select/Index.html)

Comment: Thumbs up for the explanation but does this really work? I'm asking because I thought `stdWrap()` expects current content as the first argument. As you are passing cObject name, it looks to me like `cObjGetSingle()` method shall be called instead: `$this->cObj->cObjGetSingle($conf['jsonList'], $conf['jsonList.'])`

Comment: @cascaval, you're right - stdWrap expects content as first argument, and in our case it'll be _NULL_, that's why I'm using `jsonList.cObject` - that will instruct stdWrap to load content from given cObject, which is _CONTENT_ in our case. You approach is also correct (surely, without `.cObject` added to `jsonList`), but it limits _jsonList_ property to cObject only, so it no longer can contain plain string with stdWrap around. But in a case of current question it is also good :)

Comment: I see. That should work then. However, you are not passing *NULL* to the `stdWrap()` as the first argument. You are passing the string "CONTENT". I would say that the lines `temp.ListOfIds.userFunc.jsonList = CONTENT` and `temp.ListOfIds.userFunc.jsonList.table = tx_eepcollect_sessions` don't need to be there and the call can be `$jsonList = $this->cObj->stdWrap('', $conf['jsonList.']);`

Comment: Mmm... no - we're talking about different things, I guess =) It is _NULL_ in my case, because I have following structure: `temp.ListOfIds = USER
temp.ListOfIds.userFunc = user_IdList->get_IdList
temp.ListOfIds.userFunc.jsonList.cObject < temp.pidList`
See - there is nothing at `temp.ListOfIds.userFunc.jsonList` itself, so it will be treated as _NULL_. And string 'CONTENT' will be inside of `temp.ListOfIds.userFunc.jsonList.cObject`. And, yes, you're right: call can be `$jsonList = $this->cObj->stdWrap('', $conf['jsonList.']);`

Comment: Now I understand where the confusion comes from. :-) I thought the second block of code in your answer is also part of the solution as after all you still have to define `temp.ListOfIds = USER` and the user function and you are using `$conf['jsonList']` in `stdWrap()` while it actually doesn't exist.